# Is there a difference 'app/**/*.html' and 'app/**/**/*.html' as a gulp.src file list?

Tags: node.js, gulp

My config file for gulp watch looks like this:

```
var files = [
        'app/**/*.html',
        'app/**/**/*.html',
        'app/**/**/**/*.html'
];
```

I'm confused about the difference with ** and *

Could all of these be just one line if I use ** ?

Comment: Nope, no difference. You don't need more than 1 `**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pattern is call "globbing". Gulp-watch uses the "node-glob" module for that:

https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob#glob-primer

> - * Matches 0 or more characters in a single path portion
> - ** If a "globstar" is alone in a path portion, then it matches zero or more directories and subdirectories searching for matches. It does not crawl symlinked directories.

So, in your case the three patterns are redundant, they would produce the same fileset.

Answer (score 0):

To be short

`**`  represents all Folder

`*.js` represents all File with .js extension

`*.*` represents all file with any extension

https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#glob-primer